# Doesn't conform to protocol error when trying to apply extension with PAT

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I don't understand why this is failing:

```
import Foundation
import simd

protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype ElementType
    func reduce_add(x:Self) -> ElementType
}

extension float2 : TestProtocol {
    typealias ElementType=Float
}
```

I get a "Type 'float2' does not conform to protocol 'TestProtocol'" error in the Playground.  Specifically it tells me:

> Playground execution failed: Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:3:1:
>   error: type 'float2' does not conform to protocol 'TestProtocol'
>   extension float2 : TestProtocol { ^ Untitled
>
> Page.xcplaygroundpage:6:10: note: protocol requires function
>   'reduce_add' with type 'float2 -> ElementType'
>       func reduce_add(x:Self) -> ElementType

When I look at the `simd` interface, however, I see:

```
/// Sum of the elements of the vector.
@warn_unused_result
public func reduce_add(x: float2) -> Float
```

and if I call `reduce_add(float2(2.4,3.1))`, I get the right result.  ElementType is `typealias`ed to `Float`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing

```
public func reduce_add(x: float2) -> Float
```

from the `simd` module is a *global function*, and your protocol
requires an *instance method*.

You cannot require the existence of a global function with a protocol.
If you want an instance method then it could look like this:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype ElementType
    func reduce_add() -> ElementType
}

extension float2 : TestProtocol {
    func reduce_add() -> Float {
        return simd.reduce_add(self)
    }
}

let f2 = float2(2.4, 3.1)
let x = f2.reduce_add()
print(x) // 5.5
```

Comment: Ah.  I guess I got confused by the fact that you can require operators, which are global, but apparently a special case.  So if my goal is to generalize across vector types, I need to mirror the entire simd library as instance functions?

Comment: @Omegaman:  Yes. (At least no alternative comes into my mind at present.)