# Making Swift generics play with overloaded functions

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to build a generic type `MyStruct<T>` that can use either `Float` or `Double` for internal storage.  In the initializer, I'm passing an argument of type T (which I intend to be either `Float` or `Double`).  That initializer calls some trig functions such as `sin()` and `cos()`.  Both of those functions are overloaded in the system libraries to provide `Float` and `Double` versions.

```
var f:Float=1.2
var d:Double=1.2

sin(f) //0.9320391
sin(d) //0.9320390859672263
```

Trouble is, I can't use them in my generic struct.  A stripped down case would look like this:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    var v:T

    init(x:T){v=sin(x)}
}
```

Because:

> Playground execution failed: Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:9:17:
>   error: cannot invoke 'sin' with an argument list of type '(T)'
>       init(x:T){v=sin(x)}
>
> Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:9:17: note: overloads for 'sin' exist with these partially matching parameter lists:
>   (Float), (Double)
>       init(x:T){v=sin(x)}

It seems like there should be a way to make this work, but it feels a lot like [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37339438/2571165).  Where the comments suggest there is no way to require the existence of a global function.

I can force the situation by using a construct such as:

```
init(x:T){v=T(sin(Double(x)))}
```

and putting a constraint on T that it can be constructed from a `Double`, but that seems to defeat the purpose of making the `Float` version of the struct, which is to reduce computation effort when this is used in a critical loop of code.

It feels like this would have been easier if `sin()` had been defined in the library as a generic function rather than an overloaded function:

```
func sin<T:FloatingPointType> (x:T) -> T
```

but it is what it is.

Is there a way for me to build a library that is Float/Double agnostic on top of the standard libraries without adding a lot of overhead?

Comment: "Is there a way for me to do this without adding a lot of overhead?" I'm not sure what "this" is supposed to be, but `sin` is several C functions that know nothing of Swift generics (so you can't use a placeholder type as its argument) or of Swift protocols (so you can't use a FloatingPointType as its argument).

Comment: @matt, By "this" I mean to create a library that is Float/Double agnostic on top the standard libraries.  That seems like an obvious use of generics, but I haven't been able to more than the most basic of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this the way `sin()` is currently implemented in Swift. It would have to be treated as an operator (like how `Equatable` and `==` works) in order to allow you to add it as a protocol requirement.

[@matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369835/2976878) is a nice quick fix, but if you want something more permanent, you may want to consider creating a protocol and then extending the floating point types in order to allow you to overload the `sin()` function with a generic version.

```
protocol FloatingPointMathType : FloatingPointType {
    var _sinValue : Self { get }
}

extension Float : FloatingPointMathType {
    var _sinValue : Float {return sin(self)}
}

extension Double : FloatingPointMathType {
    var _sinValue : Double {return sin(self)}
}

extension CGFloat : FloatingPointMathType {
    var _sinValue : CGFloat {return sin(self)}
}

func sin<T:FloatingPointMathType>(x:T) -> T {return x._sinValue}
```

<sup>(Feel free to add more math functions)</sup>

We're having to use a 'shadow' calculated property here to make up for the fact that we can't simply use `sin()` as a protocol requirement. It's not ideal – but probably about as good as you're going to get.

You can now go ahead and use `sin()` as a generic function:

```
struct MyStruct<T:FloatingPointMathType> {
    var v : T

    init(x:T) {
        v =  sin(x)
    }
}
```

```
print(MyStruct(x: Float(3.0)).v) // 0.14112
print(MyStruct(x: Double(3.0)).v) // 0.141120008059867
print(MyStruct(x: CGFloat(3.0)).v) // 0.141120008059867
```

Comment: This seems to do it without the runtime overhead.  I think Swift will probably inline most of the additional function calls.  I went with `func sin() -> Float {return Foundation.sin(self)}` instead of a var, but I think it's 6 in 1, half a dozen in the other.  I'm not sure why you don't need to add the Foundation namespace to avoid a reference loop, maybe because your generic function is just another overload?  The generic function to keep the function call syntax is a nice touch.

Comment: @Omegaman Happy to help :) The reason I can omit the `Foundation.` namespace from the non-generic `sin` function call is that Swift will always prefer calling the function with the more specific parameter type. Therefore it will prefer the non-generic `sin` function over the generic one when you come to pass in a non-generic type, so there's no issue – although obviously there's no harm in putting it in. As for whether to use a computed property or function, I suspect it'll make no difference whatsoever when it comes to optimisation, just whatever you prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Might try something like this:

```
struct MyStruct<T:FloatingPointType> {
    var v:T
    init(x:T){
        switch x {
        case is Float:
            v = sin(x as! Float) as! T
        case is Double:
            v = sin(x as! Double) as! T
        case is CGFloat:
            v = sin(x as! CGFloat) as! T
        default:v = 0.0 as! T
        }
    }
}
```

Seems to work:

```
let s = MyStruct(x:Float(3))
s.v // 0.14112
let s2 = MyStruct(x:Double(3))
s2.v // 0.1411200080598672
let s3 = MyStruct(x:CGFloat(3))
s3.v // 0.1411200080598672
```

Comment: You could make this slightly nicer with `case let x as Float` etc. That way you can eliminate the first set of forced downcasts.

Comment: This works in a pinch and I was afraid it might be the only option until @originaluser2 found a way to do it with some clever protocol specializations and a generic function to hide the mess.  The main downside here, is the overhead of the runtime type checking.