# Swift BinaryFloatingPoint generic exposes compile error on log10() invocation

Tags: swift, generics

What protocol should T complies with to pass this error?

```
class func magnitude<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ n: T) where T: CVarArg {
    // …

    let p = Int(log10(n))

    // …
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Cannot invoke 'log10' with an argument list of type '(T)'
```

Comment: There is (as far as I can tell) no generic `log10` function, only concrete overloads for Float/Double/CGFloat arguments. You'll have to define your own protocol if you need it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175915/how-to-write-a-generic-function-for-floating-point-values-in-swift .

Comment: Or this one (possible duplicate?) [Making Swift generics play with overloaded functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369649/making-swift-generics-play-with-overloaded-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martin R tips, I came up with the following (I added fictional code so that one can compile it), which works nice:

```
protocol FloatingPointMathType : BinaryFloatingPoint, CVarArg {
    var _log10Value : Self { get }
}

extension Float: FloatingPointMathType {
    var _log10Value : Float {return log10(self)}
}

extension Double: FloatingPointMathType {
    var _log10Value : Double {return log10(self)}
}

extension CGFloat: FloatingPointMathType {
    var _log10Value : CGFloat {return log10(self)}
}

func log10<T:FloatingPointMathType>(_ x:T) -> T {return x._log10Value}

class Format {
    class func magnitude<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ n: T) -> Int {

        let p = Int(log10(n))

        return p
    }
}

let d: Double = 12.0
print(Format.magnitude(d))
```